# Issue setting font color in Visualforce page using stylesheets

Tags: visualforce, stylesheets

I am trying to set properties on a column using a stylesheet instead of embedded style values.  However I cannot get the stylesheet method to work when applying color to the text.  I am fairly new to VF and this is my first time trying to use a stylesheet.

Here is the component that renders correctly using style option:

```
apex:column value="{!i.Display_Value6__c}" style="background:#DAF6FF;color:red"
```

Here is the component using the stylesheet which correcly applies the background color but not the font:

```
apex:column value="{!i.Display_Value6__c}" styleClass="colorstyle_red"
```

here is the contents of the style sheet:

```
   .colorstyle_red { 
    background: #DAF6FF;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: I have helped edit your post so that the code sections are formatted. Usually such problems in stylesheets are either because the stylesheet has not be referenced correctly or there is a syntax issue in the stylesheet code. Anyways what is the <br> doing in your style sheet code? Is this the html version of your style sheet class? Are you sure that the background color is not being set up somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Richard! IThe <br> are not actually in my code but were my ineffective method to make my post more readable. Still haven't quite mastered the art of posting code to stack exachange. I am really sure the style sheet is correctly setting the background color as I tried different colors in the stylesheet and they were applied as expected.

Comment: Np debra. It will take some time to get used to it. I have made edits to your code to make it more readable. But they need to be peer reviewed before taking effect. :)

Comment: This is probably something to do with CSS Precedence. If you are not familiar with this it can catch you out. My guess is that it works when applied as style because the directly styled CSS takes highest precedence. But there is likely some other rule or css getting in the way. Learning how to use the page inspector of your browser is the only way to figure this out. What other CS is getting loaded in your page. Can you share the code where all CS is linked and the order of your CS and the other CS.

Comment: see if adding `!important` after each declaration in your style parameter. If that fixes it then the issue is defiantly due to CSS Precedence.

Comment: Please try chome inspector which shows all styles and which are in effect and which are not (being overridden). This seems more like a css precedence issue.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your helpful tips to a newbie.   I did try !important but it didn't seem to help.   For now due to time deadlines I will keep the code without using the stylesheet (unfortunate) and when time permits try more options to see if I can get stylesheets to work with this simple page.